# Creating an ARM Dissassembler Need help on MUL Instruction (ARM Assembly)

Tags: assembly, arm, multiplication

I am trying to create a disassembler for ARM as I want to learn ARM assembly language. I have read from another StackOverflow thread that this is the best way to do it. So one thing I am having trouble is getting the decode of multiply correctly.

Here is an example of a disassembled object file.

00008054 <_start>:
 ==============ommitted irrelevant instructions ====

```
8064:   e0010092    mul r1, r2, r0
```

From the reference manual (http://www.nyx.net/~troddis/ARM.html), a multiply instruction should have a value of "1001" in bits [4-7] inclusive. However, e0010092 in binary is "11100010000000000001000000000010" which have 0000 in bits 4-7.

Is there something obvious that I am missing? I am using CodeSourcery's ARM 2012.09-64 cross compiler...

Comment: *"I am trying to create a disassembler for ARM as I want to learn ARM assembly language. I have read from another StackOverflow thread that this is the best way to do it."* Totally wrong. To learn ARM assembly, make assembly programs (like any other (programming) language).

Comment: @m0skit0 +1 yes.  I wonder what thread gave that silly idea to OP?  I'd like to know so I can downvote it as, well, batshit-crazy.

Comment: A straightforward way to learn assembly for a given CPU is to make the compiler "transliterate" small C snippets with well-defined/constrained behaviour into object code and _then disassemble the result_. The advantage of this for beginners is twofold: a) the disassembly isn't cluttered with "meta-stuff" (as the asm source created by the compiler is - labels, directives, comments, ...), and b) unlike asm sources, the disassembly shows the instruction opcode bytes as well. That said, this method of becoming familiar with asm doesn't mandate / isn't helped by you writing your own disassembler.

Comment: Actually knowing the opcodes really is useless (except on very specific subjects). You won't be able to remember that anyway. Knowing how the opcodes are and how they are generated from assembly instructions might be worth it, but still it's far less important than knowing what instructions actually do and how to write correct programs with that assembly.

Comment: Hey guys, I appreciate the comments. This is the thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/270078/resources-for-learning-arm-assembly and one of the answers that has the 2nd highest vote ( i think) has advocated that. So should I continue with my quest?

Comment: @dean: Not sure why you bumped me, but fine :) I've put a snippet below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How'd you convert it to binary? Hex 9 is exactly binary 1001.

Comment: opps. My bad. Now I feel so stupid. I used ruby's conversion and for some reason it messed up the values. Is there a way to delete this question?

Answer (score 0):

Converting hex to binary can largely be done "in your head" if you remember:

```
8421|8421...
===========
1011|1001...
8 21|8  1...
```

The upper line are the powers of two which make up a hexadecimal digit - `8+4+2+1 == 0xf`. The lower line is some arbitrary binary; to convert that to hex, add the powers-of-two set in the 4-binary-digit unit (a "nibble"), third line. Every nibble is one hex digit. So do that for every nibble and you've got the hex-from-binary. In the case pf the above, `8+2+1 == 0xb` and `8+1==9` so you have `10111001 == 0xB9` (assuming you count bit zero as the rightmost one; if you consider bit zero the leftmost one, it'd be `0x9B`, welcome to the world of endianness ... but that's another question)

The reverse is also simple; for your number:

```
e   |0   |0   |1   |0   |0   |9   |2   |
842 |    |    |   1|    |    |8  1|  2 |
1110|0000|0000|0001|0000|0000|1001|0010|
```

Again, the top line is the hex digits, the middle line the powers of two which summed up give the hex digit, and the bottom are the bit sequence.

I tend to use the calculator to convert decimal-to-hex and vice versa, but binary-to/from-hex, do in my head as per above.

If you really want to use a calculator, UN*X `bc` is helpful for all sorts of numerical conversions:

```
$ echo "ibase=16;obase=2;B8F7D335" | bc
10111000111101111101001100110101
$ echo "ibase=16;B8F7D335" | bc
3103249205
$ echo "obase=16;ibase=2;10111000111101111101001100110101" | bc
B8F7D335
```

The default "base" is ten, so no need to explicitly specify input / output number base if you're converting to/from ten. Introductions to `bc` are all over the web; like [this one](http://www.basicallytech.com/blog/?/archives/23-command-line-calculations-using-bc.html).